# How can I access and use multiple javascript libraries?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and programming in general.  I have been working on a web app that solves simple algebraic equations.  I am using two libraries, algebra.js and katex.js.  How do I use both libraries in my script?  I would like to keep this as a client-side application.

I have looked at node.js but my understanding is that node is for server-side development.  I have looked at RequireJS but that doesn't seem to handle directories well.  Recently I found Enderjs which seems to use npm and allow for client-side development and still make use of require().

What should I use to make a web app like this? Please let me know if there is anymore information that is needed.

Comment: Are you encountering an error when you include both scripts in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most basic way to do this is to include multiple script tags at the top of your html file. So:

```
<head>
    <script src="path/to/library1.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/library2.js"></script>
    <script src="path/to/my/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
```

This will load more than one onto the page. The order might matter - be wary of which dependencies your chosen libraries have. For example, some will depend on jQuery, so you should load jQuery first then those that depend on it. Order is top down.

In my example, if we pretend library2 depends on library1, then the example would work. However if library1 depended on library2, it would not.

Comment: make sure these lines are before your script in the HTML. usually scripts get included either in the head section or at the bottom of the body section.

Comment: So if I did something like this:  
`<script src="algebra.min.js"></script>`  
 `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/KaTeX/0.5.1/katex.min.js"></script>`  
 Could I then also use a script tag for a file that uses functions from the previous script tags or do I just type the javascript inline? How would I call those functions?

Comment: I've updated my post to include a javascript file you might have created yourself

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to include the script tags directly in your html file like so (this assumes that you have the `algebra.js` file in the same folder as your html file):

```
<script src="algebra.js"></script>
```

If you are loading the library from the internet you have to use the full web path in the `src` attribute, for example loading the jQuery library from a cdn (content distribution network):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```